# How do you organize example code for future reference?

Tags: organization

Very often when programming, I find that I encounter problems that I have solved in the past, but don't remember the solution to.  I've been trying to record notes and code snippets of solutions I come up with so that I can reference them in the future. but I don't know the best way organize my solutions so that I can quickly and productively find them in the future.

Right now I've been putting code examples into separate files in a big directory, but it can get hard to find things for the future.  It would also be nice to have the ability to search for keywords so that I can quickly find what I'm looking for.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to organize a personal body of code to use as reference for future programming?

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I tried to organize my folders and make a "Dictionary" of different problems with their solutions. Unfortunately, I found it was very time consuming even though it was well organized with a few collegues.

If you're working with common languages (C#, VB.Net, Java, html, javascript, css, ...), Internet is your best repository. I find it faster to type what I want on a search engine (or stackoverflow directly) than browse into a home made repository.


If you still want to make a repository, I prefered keeping the entire projects and have a "master file (excel can do)" where you can search for keywords and find which project deals with the problem.

Once in a project, you can do another search for the exact location. I found it less time consuming to do another search than pointing the diffrerents files/functions to look at in the "master file".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine introduced me to [Notion](https://www.notion.so/). It's basically like Evernote but has quite a lot more and you can write code blocks etc. Ever since, I use that to keep references of code and some explanations etc. Most of the time I'm too lazy to even copy and paste code snippets I find on Stack Overflow and so I just copy links into there as well. Anyway, I think some sort of integrated solution like this is pretty great.